# show full text on mouse over or hover on a <p:commandLink>

Tags: hover, onmouseover, commandlink

One of the table column displays commandLink in its rows, whose value is a long text. I am displaying only a portion of that text and when a user hovers on the link I want a pop up or something that will display the full text and hide it when the mouse is away.
How would I approach this, tried ajax event  but didn't work. 
     Its 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is wondering, this is what I did finally using tooltip...

```
    <div id="sub" style="width:175px;white-space:nowrap;text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden;">

            <p:commandLink id ="myLink" value="#{message.subject}" ajax="true" 
                           update=":messageForm:grid">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{message}"
                                             target="#{myBean.selectedMessage}"/>

            </p:commandLink>

            <p:tooltip for="myLink" value="#{message.subject}" showEffect="slide" hideEffect="slide" style="background-color:#FFFFCC;border:1px dotted #000000;" />
        </div>
```